# Restart connection in telegram bot

Tags: python, python-3.x, firebird, telegram-bot

I have a problem with a telegram bot or with a database connection. After receiving the result from the database, I can't retrieve the result. But, when I restart the connection - it works. How can I configure the connection correctly? and could not attach the code?

part of my code:

```
@bot.message_handler(commands=['pos'])
def get_reports(message):
    user_markup = telebot.types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(one_time_keyboard=True)
    result_pos = cur.fetchall()
    for row in result_pos:
        bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, row )


if __name__ == '__main__':
     bot.polling(none_stop=True)


con.commit()
cur.close()
con.close()
```

Comment: `After receiving the result from the database, I can't retrieve the result.` what do you mean ?

Comment: I mean, when I send a request in a telegram to the database, I get the result only once. When I try to send a request again, I get nothing

Comment: so you do not know if you do "Receive the result from database" or not on the second, third and other attempts. Try using FBProfiler.sf.net on your Firebird 2.5+ server to peep into bot-to-database traffic, to see WHEN and WHICH requests your bot sends. Will give you more info to share with Python programmers

Comment: Thank you very much for the program, it's very good for jobs. But, what exactly need from the program ?  When I got the result, the monitor writes: "EXECUTE_STATEMENT_FINISH ". After there was no more traffic, even when you send a request

Comment: All in all, you would need to learn programming, then your will need to learn programming in Python, then what you will need to learn programmin telegram bots in Python. Since i know neither Python nor Telegram i can not help you much there. But in general, for programming, you must make some mind picture how your program should behave, find ways to observe actual behaviour, and then keep fixing differences between real and ideal behavior. The "observe actual behaviour" i try to help you with, rest is for Python or Telegram programmers.

Comment: Also, i do not see in your code where you do open `con` and `cur`. I think "EXECUTE_STATEMENT_FINISH" is executed when `cur.close()` is executed, which seems to mean your bot program exits. I guess it does not wait for another command until forever but exits immediately after first time. I think you have to consult Python and Telegram manual how to make non-exiting bot program, that runs forever in an infinite loop.  BTW, `con.close()` should show something like CONNECTION_CLOSED in the FBProfiler

Comment: Can you do a "step by step" debugging of your bot? Is there any Python IDE which will let you catch the Telegram bot executing, pause it and set you in control of program riunning one line at time? If not - you would have to add many "logging" commands to your bot, but it is less flexible. For example, before `user_markup =` command you may insert a command that show some text on the screen, just for the sake of knowing if the handler was invoked at all or never again.

Comment: Thank you very much for your advice! I found the problem and fixed it. The problem was in the bot code. I did not carefully write the code

Comment: additionally, i would argue that `cur.close` should go before `con.commit`. A transaction kind of 'contains', 'wraps around' one or many statements, not the other way. So logically you have to "close the jar" of statements first, and the one of the "containing" transaction later.